# Passing a literal value to a div attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, literals

Just getting into development and I have a seemingly simple issue that keeps throwing errors.

I am trying to add a widget to my page but there is a catalog number that needs to be set as an attribute for the widget div, as well as, in the link and text later.

Literal value on page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litCatalogNumber" runat="server" />
```

And where I need the value:

```
<div id='myWidget'productid=’LitCatalogNumber​’>
<a href='https://www.test.com/test/LitCatalogNumber'> View product reviews for LitCatalogNumber</a>
```

To be clear I want the literal value of litCatalogNumber to be set as a string in 3 locations:

1. productid=’ **LitCatalogNumber**’ (In the div attribute for the widget)
2. a href='https://www.test.com/test/' + **LitCatalogNumber​**  (In the link)
3. View product reviews for **LitCatalogNumber​** (In the link text)

Any help, even suggesting something to go read up on would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried code blocks <% %> and @ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code blocks <%=litProductNumber.Text%> in place of litProductNumber
P.N:I can't comment

This might be helpful:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.